# Moment.js: how to update the time every minute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to display time on my webpage. I have the html div:

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
<script>
    moment.tz.add('America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0');                                                                         
    var newYork = moment.tz("America/New_York").format('HH:mm a');
    $('#time').append( "Current time in New York: "+newYork );
</script>
```

When I run the page, it gives me the correct time, but it doesn't change with every minute, so even after 10 minutes or so I get the time that was visible when I loaded the page. Is there any way to keep the time updated? 
Here's my fiddle so far: http://jsfiddle.net/93pEd/132/

Comment: So, here's the question I asked myself when I read this question.  When you say update every minute, do you mean that verbatim?  As in, regardless of when the users load the page (ex 10:32:43) you'd like it to refresh every minute (ex 10:33:43) or do you mean every minute ON the minute?

Comment: wow, that's a good question that I didn't think through... I want to show the current time in different timezone (in my case it's new york) and do it as simple as possible..

Comment: Just curious as depending on that answer the following answers could be affected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` to run the code every 60 seconds.

Use `html()` instead of `append()` so that the previous time is overridden.

```
function updateTime(){
    var newYork = moment.tz("America/New_York").format('HH:mm a');
   $('#time').html( "Current time in New York: "+newYork );
};

moment.tz.add('America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0');                                                                         

updateTime();
setInterval(function(){
   updateTime();
},60000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93pEd/135/

---

Heres an example using seconds also:

http://jsfiddle.net/93pEd/136/

Comment: Ok, actually - it works, but there is one small problem - when I load the page, my div is empty and it's being filled after one minute... Is there a way of filling it while starting the page?

Comment: I think you should call updateTime function every second by setting interval of 1000, to make sure that value of minute change the very moment it does on clock (timer).

Comment: @Dharmang Depends on requirements. Your increasing processing by 6000% which may not be required.

Comment: 6000% looks a big deal, but it is not in my opinion. e.g. take any example of canvas or svg animation, screen is repainted in a fraction of time. this is just a DOM update. OR maybe I am wrong, I accept in advance :).

Comment: @Dharmang It's more a case of best practice than this particular example. By default I wouldn't do something like that, unless requirements state it.

Comment: In addition to the solution you can write `var updateTime() = function() { /* ... /* }; updateTime(); setInterval(updateTime, 60000);` to write more compact code and save some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Google point me to this question, want to share mine solution for slightly different case, but fundamentally same, based on selected solution here (thanks). This solution fix gap between start and new minute (pointed by Taplar at May 6 '15 under initial post).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('.world-time').length) {
   $('.world-time').each(function () {
    updateWorldTime($(this));
   });
  }

  function updateWorldTime(el) {
   var tz = el.data('tz');
   var timeToUpdate = parseInt(moment().tz(tz).format('s'));
   timeToUpdate = (((60 - timeToUpdate) * 1000));
   el.html(moment().tz(tz).format('HH:mm'));
    
    $('.update').html((timeToUpdate / 1000));
    $('.time').html(moment().format('HH:mm:ss,SS'));

   setTimeout(function () {
    updateWorldTime(el);
   }, timeToUpdate);
  }
 });
```

```html
<span>Los Angeles: <strong data-tz="America/Los_Angeles" class="world-time">12:19</strong></span>
<span>New York: <strong data-tz="America/New_York" class="world-time">15:19</strong></span>
<span>London: <strong data-tz="Europe/London" class="world-time">20:19</strong></span>
<span>Prague: <strong data-tz="Europe/Prague" class="world-time">21:19</strong></span>
<span>Moscow: <strong data-tz="Europe/Moscow" class="world-time">23:19</strong></span>
<span>Hong Kong: <strong data-tz="Asia/Hong_Kong" class="world-time">04:19</strong></span>
<span>Sydney: <strong data-tz="Australia/Sydney" class="world-time">07:19</strong></span>

<br><br>
Wait for it:<br>
Next update in:<span class="update"></span>s.<br>
HH:mm:ss,SS <span class="time"></span><br><br><br>
Note: If snippet doesn't work, propably link to external library doesn't exists anymore (after 2022 this snippet will be broken), sorry. In real case HTML is generated by PHP, timzones from DateTime object fit to moment.js just fine.

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```